# Add a static image on PHTML page and CMS Blocks : Magento2

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-block

How I can Add a static image on PHTML page and CMS Blocks into Magento2?
in Magento 1.x it was possible using `$this->getSkinUrl('images/xyz.jpg')`

I am trying following method into Magento2

**In Phtml File:**

```
<img src=”<?= $block->getViewFileUrl(‘images/footer-logo.png’); ?>” alt=”Demo” />
```

**In CMS Blocks:**

```
<img src=”{{view url=”images/slide-bg.jpg”}}” alt=”” />
```

but it's not working properly. Please suggest me my mistakes

Comment: Your try seems good. You need to flush your cache from backend as well as remove the cache file manually from `/var/cache`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

image url Syntax is ok for both `static block` and `phtml`, But make sure that when you write this code in static block

```
<img src="{{view url='images/slide-bg.jpg'}}" alt="test" />
```

on front-end it looks like

http://localhost/magento2new/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/slide-bg.jpg

Where `Magento/luma` is `package` name and `theme` name, you can replace with your `package` and `theme` name

So you have to take care for  `slide-bg.jpg` is exist in

`pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images` directory.

**In your case,**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/footer-logo.png'); ?>" alt="Demo">
```

Syntax seems ok, but in front-end It looks  like

http://localhost/magento2new/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/footer-logo.png

So you have to make sure that `footer-logo.png` exist in

`pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images` directory.

And don't forgot about **`"[quotation marks]`**

Comment: `view` for `pub/static/frontend/Namespace/theme/locale` 
`store` for  site url

Answer (score 25):

For your custom module create a directory structure like

```
Company/Module/view/frontend/web/images/image-icon.png
```

and in phtml use following code

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Company_Module::images/image-icon.png'); ?>' alt="image-icon" width="30" height="25">
```

Comment: thx, saved me a lot of time for searching :D

Comment: @ZFNerd Most Welcome

Answer (score 14):

Easy solution:

1. Put your image on Your Magento 2 Path:

   ```
   /app/design/frontend/< Vendor >/< theme >/web/images
   ```
2. Use this code to call the image in phtml file:

   ```
   echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.jpg');
   ```

Comment: Great and easy solution!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you would also like to keep things a little more organised you can add images for your overridden core modules under your custom theme. For example, I need an image for the newsletter form. I added an image in

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Newsletter/web/images/envelope.png
```

and in my `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml` file I used it like below to get the image source

```
$this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Newsletter::images/envelope.png');
```

I use Magento v2.2

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using an inline image:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "path/to/image.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$imagedata = base64_encode($content);
fclose($handle);
?>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?= $imagedata; ?>" alt="alt text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                        ->init($mainProduct, 'product_base_image')
                        ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                        ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                        ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                        ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                        ->resize(281, 281)->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Module image** : `$block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/test.jpg');`

**Use Theme image** : `$block->getViewFileUrl('images/test.jpg');`