# How to get image in PHTML file?

Tags: image, phtml, magento2.3.4

Image path -> **app/design/frontend/Mycustom/Mytheme/web/image/one.png** how to get image in PHTML (app/design/frontend/Mycustom/Mytheme/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml) file,

```
<?php  echo __('Search');?>
```

I need to show **image** instead of text **Search**, any help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call static images in phtml by:

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/my-logo.png'); ?>' alt="Logo">
```

Img Path:

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/web/images/my-logo.png
```

Ref: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93688/add-a-static-image-on-phtml-page-and-cms-blocks-magento2/93697#answer-93697)

Comment: Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328464/57334   How to create custom space below menu bar and move minicart element into this space, any help thanks.

Comment: Sure, let me try....